# Horizontal slide - defining start and end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a horizontal slide on a div (using relative positioning) that looks like this :

[image]

It slides left and right accordingly, but I'm having problems making it stop at both start and end of the slide container, so it ends up like this :

[image]

Here's the JS (jquery) :

```
$('.timeline-nav').on('click', function() {

    if (!anim)
    {
        anim = true;

        var pos = $(this).hasClass('left') ? 320 : -320;

        pos = parseInt($('.timeline-content-wrapper').css('left')) + pos;

        $('.timeline-content-wrapper').animate({'left': pos}, 600, function() {
            anim = false;
        });
    }

    return;
});
```

**Edit** : [live example](http://sofia-silva.com/agenda/test.php)

Comment: can you please post your demo ?

Comment: @yoda That site is blocked at my workplace :c Any chance of a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See it all working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yUe23/1/

I have changed some classes (timeline-content-wrapper) to ids and imagined some HTML around it (timeline-content-mask)

```
var anim=false;
var pos=0;
var originalPos=0;

$(function() {

    originalPos=$('#timeline-content-wrapper').offset().left;


    $('.timeline-nav').click( function() {

        if (!anim) {

            var $wrapper=$('#timeline-content-wrapper');
            var $mask=$('#timeline-content-mask');        

            var pos = $(this).hasClass('left') ? 200 : -200;
            var wid=$wrapper.width();
            var maskWid=$mask.width();
            var oldPos=$wrapper.offset().left;

            anim = true;

            // alert(parseInt($wrapper.offset().left)+" "+pos+" "+originalPos+" "+originalPos+" "+wid+" "+maskWid);

            pos = parseInt($wrapper.offset().left)-originalPos + pos;

            if(pos<-wid+maskWid) pos=-wid+maskWid;
            else if(pos>0) pos=0;

            $wrapper.animate({'left': pos}, 600, function() {
                anim = false;
            });

        }

        return;
    });


});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pos = parseInt($('.timeline-content-wrapper').css('left')) + pos;
if (pos < -1120) pos = -1120;
if (pos > 0) pos = 0;
```

The code could be shorter, but that's more understandable :). The first if depends on the width of the elements; maybe you need to change it or calculate at runtime.

Comment: Counting the children elements width was not giving me the proper value, but your contribution gave me the hint to get there, +1

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
pos = Math.min(parseInt($('.timeline-content-wrapper').css('left')) + pos, 0);
```

I'm assuming the wrapper div isn't supposed to have a positive left value.

Answer (score 0):

On fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ktszm/5/

```
        var max_width = 250;      
        var width_of_viewport = 200;            
        var stopper = max_width - width_of_viewport;  
        var container_position = $('.timeline-content-wrapper').position().left;



        if(container_position == 0 && $(this).hasClass('left')) 
        { 
           pos = 0; 
        }
        else if(container_position == (stopper*-1) && !$(this).hasClass('left')) 
        { 
           pos = 0; 
        }
        else 
        { 
           $('.timeline-content-wrapper').animate({'left': '+='+pos}, 600, function() {
                anim = false;
            });
        }
    }
```

​